# Can repetitive music help remember by increasing theta waves?

Tags: memory, brain-training, music, brain-waves

Can repetitive music (minimal) help remember by increasing theta waves?

As far as I understand theta waves are involved in memory tasks. If correct, can I try increase theta waves with audio neuro-feedback to help remember or find clarity on a question? I am thinking about something very simple like drumming with 4-6 beats per second.

Cheers! k

Comment: What makes you believe this could be the case?

Comment: Internet searches seem to indicate that theta waves are involved in memory tasks. When I listen to monotone drumming around 4-6 beat per second (4-6hz) I am much better at remembering things.